# Move every first line of a pair of cells in a column to the same row to the left of the second line

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How to move every first line (digits) of a pair of cells in a column to the same row to the left of the second line (names)? The pairs of cells are at a random distance in this column.

```
0117-000-00
Mrktble Equity Securities

0118-010-00
Allow for Doubtful Accts


0119-000-00
Other Receivables

0120-000-00
Employee Advances



0121-000-00
Prepaid Expenses
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, depending on how much steps you want, a formula will require a couple imo:

1. In B1, just put the number, it's only for the first cell.
2. In B2, put the formula:

   ```
   =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A2,4)*1),MID(A2,5,1)="-"),A2)
   ```
3. Scroll the formula to the bottom of your table and copy/paste the values in place.
4. Insert a filter, filter on FALSE in column B and delete all the rows with FALSE
5. You can sort to get rid of the blank rows (or add a column containing incrementing count before sorting to get the original order).

Comment: Sorry but I have all values in column B! If I drag the formula in column B, I will delete my data! Where should I paste this formula? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I am on the 600th line!. 10x more to go!

Comment: @user250648 Omg, that's a lot of manual work you did! D: Just change the references to column B and put it in column C: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(LEFT(B2,4)*1),MID(B2,5,1)="-"),B2)`

Comment: @user250648 I hope you don't have to do all those manual editing again! ^^

Comment: How to delete the account numbers in column B without shifting anything?

Comment: @user250648 You can put a filter on column C on all the `FALSE` and select all the cells that need to be deleted, then push the Delete button on your keyboard.